# Is it possible to get intellisense help for object keys added via generic function

Tags: typescript

Here is a basic example. Is it possible to get keys in intellisense?

[Code example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=export%20class%20Test%3CK%20extends%20string%2C%20V%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20private%20data%3A%20%7B%5BP%20in%20K%5D%3A%20V%7D%20%3D%20%7B%7D%20as%20any%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20addValue%20(key%3A%20K%2C%20value%3A%20V)%3A%20this%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.data%5Bkey%5D%20%3D%20value%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20build%20()%3A%20%7B%5BP%20in%20K%5D%3A%20V%7D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this.data%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20test%20%3D%20new%20Test()%0D%0A%20%20%20%20.addValue('A'%2C%20123)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20.addValue('B'%2C%20'111')%0D%0A%20%20%20%20.build()%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Atest.%20%2F*%20A%20%7C%20B%20*%2F)

```
export class Test<K extends string, V> {


    private data: {[P in K]: V} = {} as any;

    addValue (key: K, value: V): this {
        this.data[key] = value;
        return this;
    }

    build (): {[P in K]: V} {
        return this.data;
    }
}

const test = new Test()
    .addValue('A', 123)
    .addValue('B', '111')
    .build();


test. <-- I want `test` to know about keys in `this.data`
```

Well... I should add some more text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this, but at each step (ie each `addValue` call) you need to change the type of the object to add the new key and value.

```
export class Test<T> {
    private data: T = {} as any;
    addValue<KAdd extends string, VAdd>(key: KAdd, value: VAdd){
        let newThis = this as unknown as Test<Record<KAdd, VAdd>>
        newThis.data[key] = value;
        return newThis as Test<T & Record<KAdd, VAdd>>;
    }

    build (): T {
        return this.data;
    }
}

const test = new Test()
    .addValue('A', 123)
    .addValue('B', '111')
    .build();


test.A // number
test.B // string
```